# Why is writing a std::string to cout causing an unknown operator << error?

Tags: c++, cout

I am getting an error when I try to output the return value from one of my methods:

```
Error: No operator "<<" matches these operands. Operand types are: std::ostream << std::string
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"

int main()
{
    book.setTitle("Advanced C++ Programming");
    book.setAuthorName("Linda", "Smith");
    book.setPublisher("Microsoft Press", "One Microsoft Way", "Redmond");
    book.setPrice(49.99);

    cout << book.getBookInfo(); // <-= this won't compile because of the error above.

    int i;
    cin >> i;

    return 0;
};
```

Method which should return string:

```
string Book::getBookInfo()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << title << endl << convertDoubleToString(price) << endl;

    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: You need to overload the `<< operator`.

Comment: @Rapptz - no, not here; the member function `getBookInfo` returns a string, and that string gets inserted.

Comment: I don't see `title` declared anywhere.

Comment: `str::string` - shouldn't that be `std::string`?

Comment: @Mysticial: Its all there, I just pasted the code what causes me trouble, If I use `cout` in the method without `cout` in main method it works just fine. I just wonder why this wont work the way I am presenting. :)

Comment: @therefromhere: You are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`#include <string>` is missing.

Comment: Problem solved... I feel stupid today lol. I didn't have it there and `cout` was working OK. Thanks, I'll remember for next time.

Answer (score 2):

How did the code get the definition of `string`? The header `<string>` also declares the stream inserter.